# How to upload a Excel sheet in Angular and receive it in Django

Tags: python, django, angular, typescript, file-upload

I'm new to Angular and Django. My requirement is to build a webpage, from which user can upload a excel sheet. I need to receive this excel sheet in back-end (Django) and perform operations on that file. I checked various examples but somehow I couldn't do it.

html.ts ..

```
<form>
<input type="file" (change)="selectExcel($event)">
<button type="button" (click)="uploadExcel()">Upload Excel</button>
 </form>
```

Component.ts

```
 selectExcel(event){
    this.selFile=event.target.files[0]
  }

  uploadExcel(){
    console.log(this.selFile)
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', this.selFile,this.selFile.name);
    console.log(fd)
    this.service.fileUpload(fd)
    .subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
```

service.ts

```
 fileUpload(f){
   return this.http.post(this.API+'fileupload/',JSON.stringify(f))
 }
}
```

I'm really not sure how to receive the file in Django.. I tried the below

```
    def post(self, request):
        file = json.loads(request.body)
        print(file)
```

Comment: Your form is opening and closing properly as far as I can see, there's two form closing tags only. You also need to add the enctype in the form, something like this `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="excelUpload">`

Comment: @HellaSpace , Its not working still. I corrected the form closing tag. I added enctype in the form. Also, when do a ```console.log(fd)``` after appending, its showing empty formdata ```FormData {}``` in console.